# same final variable declared in two interface and implemented in one class

Tags: java

Hi I have two interface **Ainterface** and **Binterface** having same static final variable as '**i**' which is declared as **10** and **20** respectively, I am implementing these two interfaces two my class **InterfaceCheck** where I am declaring same interface variable as static and final and initialized to **30**.  When I try to print the value of **i** in my class I am getting 30 as output. can some one explain me why I am able to reinitialize **i**  to some other value even though its a final variable.

**CODE**

```
public interface Ainterface {

    public final static int i=10;

}

public interface Binterface {

    public static final int i=20;

}


public class InterfaceCheck implements Ainterface,Binterface {

    public static final int i=30;   

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

**>> output : 30**

Comment: Because it's not in the same class??!!

Comment: @JonathanHenson I wouldn't consider a static final variable as "state".

Answer (score 11):

Class fields are always resolved on the static type of the reference.

In

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

it implicitly does

```
System.out.println(InterfaceCheck.i);
```

so that is what you see.

Also, static fields are not inherited.

Answer (score 5):

Static variables belong to the class itself (not to the instance) and these variables are not inherited by child class or implementing class.

Therefore:

```
public class InterfaceCheck implements Ainterface,Binterface {
    public static final int i=30;   
}
```

is not overriding `i` from those 2 interfaces. **It is actually declaring a new independent static final variable.**

Comment: if its declaring a new independent variable, what is the point of making i as final in my interface?

Comment: As I wrote those variables are all independent but you can use other var as `Ainterface.i`

Answer (score 1):

Java has single inheritance because multiple inheritance has the problem of which members to pick when inherited classes collide on member names.  But Java provides interfaces because that provides much of the power of multiple inheritance (additional behaviors) without the risk of name collision (but at the cost of choosing which methods so provide when method signature collision occurs).

Allowing class variables in interfaces is a relaxation of this rule, but was probably allowed because of where the member variable is located (one per class).  As anubhava and  Sotirios said they are not inherited, but declaring a new member, obscuring the inherited variable.

Your question concerns lexical scope.  Since you have declared three 'public' variables which are class members, then you need to resolve scope.  Since you have two inherited interfaces, do you really mean to define/set your own class variable, or to modify one or both of the inherited interface class variables?

Comment: My another doubt is being final variable, how i can reinitialize the same variable i in my implemented class?

Comment: Do you want a single variable shared by all objects of the class, or one variable per class?

Comment: Do you want a constant, or a variable?  Is this something you want to share, but allow to change?  Maybe what you want is a private (rather than public) variable, and then a method to set the value?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you play around with the code to understand it fully whats going on, Very old thread here but all the same just wanted to add the following:

Comment out the static class "i" and when you run the code you will see java telling you "reference to i is ambiguous" ie, it does not know which one you want to call as it exists in both interfaces. Now un-comment the class static "i" and add two more printouts with the reference to both interfaces. As they are static this is allowed.

```
public static final int i=30;

public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(Ainterface.i);
        System.out.println(Binterface.i);
    }
```

30
10
20

Again if you remove the InterfaceCheck class static "i" constant and remove one of the interfaces it implements, say Binterface. You can reference the constant from Ainterface without its explicit reference as its the only static "i" created.

```
public class InterfaceCheck implements Ainterface {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println(i); //This will out Ainterface.i value of 10
        //System.out.println(Ainterface.i);
        //System.out.println(Binterface.i);
    }
```